# deck of cards not working

Tags: java, arrays

I can not for the life of me figure out how to do this. So I need to get the program to draw four cards, all of each different suit, if the four cards arent different it adds to count. If the four are different it returns count and exits the while loop.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    //deck of cards created


    String[] cards = {"Ace of Spades","2 of Spades","3 of Spades",
            "4 of Spades","5 of Spades","6 of Spades","7 of Spades",
            "8 of Spades","9 of Spades","10 of Spades","Jack of Spades",
            "Queen of Spades","King of Spades","2 of Diamonds",
            "3 of Diamonds","4 of Diamonds", "5 of Diamonds","6 of Diamonds",
            "7 of Diamonds","8 of Diamonds","9 of Diamonds","10 of Diamonds",
            "Ace of Diamonds","Jack of Diamonds","Queen of Diamonds",
            "King of Diamonds","Ace of Hearts","2 of Hearts","3 of Hearts",
            "4 of Hearts",  "5 of Hearts","6 of Hearts","7 of Hearts",
            "8 of Hearts","9 of Hearts","10 of Hearts","Jack of Hearts",
            "Queen of Hearts","King of Hearts","Ace of Clubs","2 of Clubs",
            "3 of Clubs","4 of Clubs","5 of Clubs","6 of Clubs","7 of Clubs",
            "8 of Clubs","9 of Clubs","10 of Clubs","Jack of Clubs",
            "Queen of Clubs","King of Clubs"};

    Random rand = new Random();
    boolean isRunning = true;
    int draw = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int unique = 0;
    String temp = "a";

    //set up drawing method
    while(isRunning = true){

        while(draw < 4 ){

            temp = cards[rand.nextInt(52)];

            draw++;

        }
        count ++;

        if( cards.equals(temp)){


            isRunning = false;
        }

        System.out.println(count);
    }
    System.out.println("Number of draws: " + count);
```

thanks for any help. I'm having a major brain fart.

Comment: So, what error do you get?

Comment: infinite loop as well as I am having a brain fart as to how to get the counter to work and stop once it has the desired cards, one from each suit.

Comment: `while(isRunning = true){` is your error. It should be `while(isRunning){`. You are actually setting `isRunning` to `true` here.

Comment: Don't entirely change your question after you've received an answer.

Comment: still having infinite loop.

Comment: @Kirikku The test `if (cards.equals(temp)) {` is also wrong. It will always be false because `cards` and `temp` are of different types. The `cards` object is of type `String[]`, while `temp` is of type `String`. What are you trying to achieve with that if-test?